# Run Node.js server file automatically after launching Electron App

Tags: node.js, github, electron

Im using **GitHub Electron** to create Desktop application with web technologies.

I'm using `Node.js` as the server, my problem is that i don't know how to run the file `server.js` just when launching the electron app.

I want to package my app for **distribution** so that i can run the **server without the command line** `$ node server.js`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just simply `require` the `server.js` file in your main file (e.g. `app.js`):

```
var app = require("app")
  , server = require("./server")
  ;

...
```

And in the `server.js` file you can have:

```
 require("http").createServer(function (req, res) {
     res.end("Hello from server started by Electron app!");
 }).listen(9000)
```

Comment: How to do it when you have an Angular 2 app with `ng serve`?

Comment: Hi I have same type of doubt in react can you please help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77619173/node-server-is-not-running-on-electron-app-launch-with-react