# Debuging expressjs server alongside electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron

I've successfully running expressjs server alongside electron as described on here:
[Run Node.js server file automatically after launching Electron App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458417/run-node-js-server-file-automatically-after-launching-electron-app)

The problem now, there is no output from command line related to server activity. I simply run

```
electron .
```

on project directory, then no other output related to the server.

Is there any way to get that server activity logged onto cli as normally I run with (like just) `node server.js` ??

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process.md

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try using the node module [concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently). This will allow you to run two commands at once and is used commonly in development with electron.

Instead of getting the server and electron to run from within the same file, separate it into a server file and an electron file. For example, one of my main development techniques is this:

```
concurrently "npm run server" "npm run start-app"
```

Which runs my hot-reload server, that my electron app connects to in development mode.
By using concurrently you can see the output of each process as well.

A good example of this technique in practice is with the [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) repository. If you're interesting in this style of development I recommend you clone that repository and give `npm run dev` a try, to see how their development process works (whether you're using React or not).