# How to start node server locally in electron app

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I'm running a NG4-Electron application and now I want to start a local node js server (Express) when the electron app starts. I have a local folder named as `local_server` at the root of the application which contains the `node server.js`. Below is my `package.json`. I'm relatively new and not being able to understand how to start the server.

```
{
  "name": "demo_app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": {
    "name": "Subbu"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "electron",
    "typescript",
    "sass"
  ],
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel webpack:watch electron:serve",
    "webpack:watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start:web": "webpack-dev-server --content-base . --port 4200 --inline",
    "build:electron:main": "tsc main.ts --outDir dist && copyfiles package.json dist && cd dist && npm install --prod && cd .. && copyfiles local_server ./dist",
    "build": "webpack --display-error-details && npm run build:electron:main",
    "build:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run build",
    "electron:serve": "npm run build:electron:main && electron ./dist --serve",
    "electron:test": "electron ./dist",
    "electron:dev": "npm run build && electron ./dist",
    "electron:prod": "npm run build:prod && electron ./dist",
    "electron:linux": "npm run build:prod && node package.js --asar --platform=linux --arch=x64",
    "electron:windows": "npm run build:prod && node package.js --asar --platform=win32 --arch=ia32",
    "electron:mac": "npm run build:prod && node package.js --asar --platform=darwin --arch=x64",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet && npm run build",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/node": "7.0.7",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.4",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.0",
    "copyfiles": "1.2.0",
    "cross-env": "5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "cssnano": "3.10.0",
    "electron": "1.7.6",
    "electron-packager": "9.1.0",
    "electron-reload": "1.2.1",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "less-loader": "4.0.5",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "postcss-url": "7.1.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "script-loader": "0.7.1",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "stylus-loader": "3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.0.6",
    "webpack": "3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.8.2"
  }
}
```

This is my `main.ts` file. Not sure how to implement the change as per the comment:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, screen } from 'electron';
import * as path from 'path';

let win, serve;
const args = process.argv.slice(1);
serve = args.some(val => val === '--serve');

if (serve) {
  require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
  });
}

function createWindow() {

  const electronScreen = screen;
  const size = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height
  });

  win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

  if (serve) {
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
  }

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null;
  });
}

try {
  app.on('ready', createWindow);

  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit();
    }
  });

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (win === null) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });

} catch (e) {
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Node.js server file automatically after launching Electron App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458417/run-node-js-server-file-automatically-after-launching-electron-app)

Comment: Why are you trying to run express in electron? There are very few reasons to do this...

Comment: @Tim I need to run express as part of my application, its a local web server. How do you think I should proceed? Any idea?

Comment: if you're starting from scratch, you should not use express at all. You should be writing the app entirely in client side JavaScript.

Comment: You could use shelljs in the main process to execute the command "node server.js"

Comment: @shashi I think I have put the question wrong, all I want is to start node server locally when my electron app starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the preload option in your BrowserWindow creator and add the file that will have the "npm" command to run.

main.js

```
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev')

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js") // add "preload"
    }
  })

  win.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? 'http://localhost:3000'
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`
  )
}
```

in here you would put the script you use In your package.json

preload.js

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

// All of the Node.js APIs are available in the preload process.
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  exec(`npm run cors-server`);
});
```

in this case, I just added a script to run my express server that will prevent "cors" issues, but obviously you will run the script you need

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "cors-server": "node server/cors-server.js",
    "electron:serve": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run start\" \"npm run electron:start\"",
    "electron:build": "npm run build && electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js",
    "electron:start": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron ."
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me understand how to run a express server during production in electron.

Comment: awesome! glad it helped you

Comment: Hate to say that I had the server running locally and now express is not running in production. Checking the logs and seems like everything should be working fine..

Comment: Did you test it in production mode? I tried the sqme logic working fin in dev but prod nop